# How get zipCode from CLPlacemark , I get it always is null?

Tags: cllocationmanager

Here's a piece of sample code:

```
[_geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:self.locationManager.location // You can pass aLocation here instead
               completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

                   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^ {
                       // do stuff with placemarks on the main thread

                       if (placemarks.count == 1) {

                           CLPlacemark *place = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                          // NSLog([place postalCode]);
                          NSString* addressString1 = [place thoroughfare];
                           addressString1 = [addressString1 stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[place.addressDictionary objectForKey:(NSString*)kABPersonAddressZIPKey]]];//
                           NSLog(@"%@",addressString1);// is null ??
                           NSlog(@"%@",place.postalCode);//is null ??

                           //[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(log) withObject:nil];
                       }

                   });
               }];
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you probably only had a 'bad' coordinate, where no zip code exists. Try the following snippet. It should display various information and the zip code '80802' at the end:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D myCoordinates = { 48.167222, 11.586111 };
CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:myCoordinates.latitude longitude:myCoordinates.longitude];

CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%d Placemarks %@", placemarks.count, placemarks);
    CLPlacemark *place = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"Placemark %@", place);
    NSLog(@"Address Dictionary: %@", place.addressDictionary);
    NSLog(@"Zip key %@", [place.addressDictionary objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressZIPKey]);

}];
```

Insert different coordinates in the first line and experiment yourself.

Comment: @Klass, this code not working for many of the lat-long. It works only for you passed. Is there any other way?

Comment: @Roshni, it heavily depends on the data that apple has about the different countries. In the US and Germany the data seems to be quite good. An Alternative would be to use the Google Maps API and its reverse geocoder: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_geocoder